Spring boot Kafka custom exponential retry not working
I am using spring boot 3.1.10
Below is my kafka consumer code
@RetryableTopic(attempts = "10",
            backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{#currentAttempt < 3 ? 60000 : (900000 * (2^(#currentAttempt - 3)))}", maxDelayExpression = "86400000"),
            
            autoCreateTopics = "true",
            retryTopicSuffix = "-retry",
            dltTopicSuffix = "-dlt",
            topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
            dltStrategy = DltStrategy.FAIL_ON_ERROR,
            timeout = "7200000",
            kafkaTemplate = "domainEventProducerKafkaTemplate")
    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.audit-event-topic}",
            containerFactory = "auditEventKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumeCoreEvent(ConsumerRecord<String, AuditEvent> consumerRecord,
                                 @Header(name = RetryTopicHeaders.DEFAULT_HEADER_ATTEMPTS, defaultValue = "1") Integer deliveryAttempt,
                                 @Header(name= KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topicName,
                                 @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.GROUP_ID)String groupId) {
        throw new RunTimeException("Testing")
    }

I am using non blocking retry. My requirement is, first 3 retries should be completed with in 10 minutes itself. Next 7 retries should not go beyond 24 hours.
I tried above code. But its not working as expected. The message is sent to first retry topic. But its not consumed
I tried this expression
 #{ #currentAttempt * 1000}

But it throwing exception.
EL1030E: The operator 'MULTIPLY' is not supported between objects of type 'null' and 'java.lang.Integer'

Tried custom policy as well. But no luck
import org.springframework.retry.backoff.BackOffContext;
import org.springframework.retry.backoff.BackOffPolicy;
import org.springframework.retry.backoff.BackOffInterruptedException;
import org.springframework.retry.RetryContext;

public class CustomBackOffPolicy implements BackOffPolicy {

    @Override
    public BackOffContext start(RetryContext retryContext) {
        return new CustomBackOffContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void backOff(BackOffContext backOffContext) throws BackOffInterruptedException {
        CustomBackOffContext context = (CustomBackOffContext) backOffContext;
        int retryCount = context.getRetryCount();
        
        // Increment retry count
        context.incrementRetryCount();
        
        // Define backoff strategy based on retry count
        long backOffPeriod;
        if (retryCount < 3) {
            // First 3 retries within 5 minutes (300,000 ms)
            backOffPeriod = 100000; // ~1.67 minutes per retry
        } else if (retryCount < 10) {
            // Next 7 retries spread over 24 hours (86,400,000 ms)
            backOffPeriod = (long) Math.pow(2, retryCount - 3) * 60000; // Exponential backoff starting from 1 minute
            backOffPeriod = Math.min(backOffPeriod, 86400000L); // Cap at 24 hours
        } else {
            // Default backoff for any additional retries (if any)
            backOffPeriod = 86400000L; // 24 hours
        }
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(backOffPeriod);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new BackOffInterruptedException("Thread interrupted while backing off", e);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomBackOffContext implements BackOffContext {
        private int retryCount = 0;

        public int getRetryCount() {
            return retryCount;
        }

        public void incrementRetryCount() {
            this.retryCount++;
        }
    }
}

@Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor retryInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder
            .stateless()
            .retryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(10)) // Total 10 retries
            .backOffPolicy(new CustomBackOffPolicy())
            .build();
    }

Can some one please help me how to make sure the retries working exponential as per my requirement
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!
